# Preg Replace on video object code - only works for first instance

Tags: object, video, embed, preg-replace, dimensions

Can anyone help me decipher why the following code only works on the first instance of width / height in an object code. I need to replace both the style which use "height: xxx ; width : xxx"  and then also replace the actual embed's height = "xxx" and width = "xxx"

here's the preg replace:

```
$vid_object = preg_replace('~((width)\s?[=:]\s?[\'"]?)[0-9]+~i','${1}600',$vid_object);

$vid_object = preg_replace('~((height)\s?[=:]\s?[\'"]?)[0-9]+~i','${1}364',$vid_object);
```

here's the video output:

```
<object style="height: 364px; width: 600px"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/UF06-2Q0-G0?version=3"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/UF06-2Q0-G0?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390"></object>
```

I think it has something to do with the replacement part of the code '${1}600' or that the results are limited to first instance.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Wasted too much time hunting when regex isn't my specialty.
Thanks
nicholas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$vid_object=preg_replace('/(width[\s:=\'"]+)\d+/i','${1}600',$vid_object);
$vid_object=preg_replace('/(height[\s:=\'"]+)\d+/i','${1}364',$vid_object);
```

It's a little broader.

When I run that on the code you provided I get

```
<object style="height: 364px; width: 600px"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/UF06-2Q0-G0?version=3"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/UF06-2Q0-G0?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="600" height="364"></object>
```

Comment: I was hoping, but it didn't work. This also works on the first pair of height /width but not the 2nd. Thanks for giving it a whirl. I don't think there's anything weird with my php code but maybe it's possible.

Comment: @nicopablo hmmm.. it worked for me using the code you provided on the question~ could it be an encoding issue?

Comment: that is weird. I don't have my sanitize function on it so I can't see what else would be encoding differently. So it definitely changes both values for you. The style ("h:w") AND the embed ("H", "W")?

Comment: yes - they are on "magic_quotes_gpc On On" . Is this good or bad? I always get confused on that ;)

Comment: bad! haha, it's most likely adding slashes to the embed code, which would break the regexp match! I think that's the culprit! =) You can add the slash to the regexp, or turn off Magic Quotes (I recommend the latter)

Comment: Hey hey Shad! You're definitely right. I just used a strip slashes on the $_POST and bango it works great now! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Shad suggested this was indeed a problem with the magic quotes being on. I just used the stripslahes on the $_POST data.